# How is string concatenation handled in Java bytecode compilation?

Tags: java, bytecode, string-concatenation, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

```
public class TestException extends Exception {

  public TestException(String msg) {
    super("This is the message: " + msg);
  }
}
```

The above code is compiled to:

```
public class TestException extends java.lang.Exception {
  public TestException(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: new           #1                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       4: dup
       5: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
       8: ldc           #7                  // String This is the message:
      10: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      13: aload_1
      14: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      17: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      20: invokespecial #17                 // Method java/lang/Exception."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      23: return
}
```

Here a `StringBuilder` object is created to concatenate the strings.

While in the same app at another place an exactly similar class is compiled to:

```
public class TestException extends java.lang.Exception {
  public TestException(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokedynamic #1,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
       7: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/Exception."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      10: return
}
```

Here `StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants()` is invoked to concatenate the strings.

Which factors determine this different behavior? How it can be predicted / controlled?

---

**PS:**
In the former case `ldc` instruction is called, which can be intercepted by overriding the [`MethodVisitor.visitLdcInsn()`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn(java.lang.Object)) method and the String can be manipulated.

To address the latter behavior [`MethodVisitor.visitInvokeDynamicInsn()`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitInvokeDynamicInsn(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.objectweb.asm.Handle,java.lang.Object...)) callback also needs to be overridden.

And I'm not sure if there are other possible behaviors too.

Comment: You seem to asking how the compiler decides which bytecode emits in each case rather than how bytecode works. What is the actual issue that you have? Why do you need to control the generation of code for concatenating strings?

Comment: You seem to be saying that the same class is compiled to two different bytecode sequences in "different places".  This doesn't make a lot of sense.  Normally a Java (source code) class is only compiled once.  Are you actually saying that you have two .class files from different builds?   If yes, the probable explanation is that they were compiled with different `javac` compilers from different JDKs.   The first version looks like an older compiler.

Comment: Do you have two source files with _exactly the same_ content in your application? If not, please edit your question to also show the second one. (FWIW, using javac 20.0.2 from OpenJDK, compiling your first code I get the bytecode from the second one.)

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-concatenation-invoke-dynamic.  The use of `invokedynamic` for string concatenation was introduced in Java 9.

Comment: @StephenC Are you suggesting that the first was compiled using Java 8 or before, and the second with Java 9 or later?

Comment: Probably.  I don't think this feature was back-ported.  Ask a **real** expert :-)

Comment: Here's the [JEP](https://openjdk.org/jeps/280) for "Indify String concatenation" that was done in Java 9.

Comment: The last section suggests that you have an actual task to solve which you didn’t describe. And no, the first variant does not consist of a single `ldc` instruction, the entire sequence from `new  #1 // java/lang/StringBuilder` up to `invokevirtual #13 // java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;` is the string concatenation. Likewise, the second variant also consists of more than one instruction, as the `aload_1` preceding the `invokedynamic` instruction also belongs to the string concatenation. Whether you have to consider more than these variants depends on your actual task.

Comment: There are at least four strategies you may encounter in practice. But do you need to identify code that is a string concatenation *semantically*, then you’d also have to consider, e.g. `"This is the message: " .concat(msg)` or `String.join("", "This is the message: ", msg)`, or *literally*, then you have the problem that you can’t distinguish the first variant from the code produced by the source code fragment `new StringBuilder().append("This is the message: ").append(msg) .toString()`. What about future Java versions, do you need to detect `STR ."This is the message: \{msg}"` or not?

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation behavior was changed in Java 9.

In the former case, the class belongs to the main app which was built using `-source 8 -target 8`. While in the latter case, the class belongs to a library which is (a dependency of the app but) built with `-source 11 -target 11`. So the compiled bytecode differs w.r.t. string concatenation.

Thanks to [@Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985) and [@Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560) for the links:

- [String Concatenation with Invoke Dynamic](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-concatenation-invoke-dynamic)
- [JEP 280: Indify String Concatenation](https://openjdk.org/jeps/280)

---

For the sake of completeness, as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488) mentioned in comments, `StringBuilder`, `String.concat()` and `String.join()` are identical when it comes to string manipulation in the compiled bytecode. Because in all three cases the string constant is first pushed onto the stack using `ldc` (where it can be simply manipulated). But in the case of `StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants()`, references of local string variables are first pushed onto the stack using `aload`.

Comment: The `ldc` instruction only pushes a constant part of the string concatenation to the operand stack, **if** there is such a constant part. For `public static String test(String s1, String s2) { return s1 + s2 + "blah"; }`, the `ldc` instruction will be *after* the local variables have been pushed. But for `public static String test(String s1, String s2) { return s1 + s2; }`, there is no constant part, hence no `ldc` instruction. Further, byte code can contain `ldc` instructions even without any string concatenation. As said, you should explain your actual task, then, we can suggest an solution.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @Holger what I asked in the question very clearly has been answered very clearly. It solves my problem. I've fixed my code. I gave a brief context of bytecode manipulation in the question to avoid "why do you care?" type comments. If I need help with `ldc` or bytecode manipulation in general, I'll post another question. Thank you for your great help.

Comment: No, the question as asked has not been answered. As I said earlier, there are at least *four* different strategies you can encounter in practice. You covered only two of them. Whether the others you have missed matter, depends on your actual task. I’m not wasting my time to explain what you’ve missed so far. Maybe it doesn’t matter to you anyway. But maybe you’re just creating a ticking time bomb. Who knows. Good luck with that.